# I am calling C function from MATLAB function in Simulink. Output of the C function is structure. How do I make this structure recognizible by MATLAB?

Tags: c, matlab, simulink

I am calling C function from MATLAB function in Simulink following this

https://mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/incorporate-c-code-using-a-matlab-function-block.html

tutorial. The only problem is that output of the C function is structure. From another link

mathworks.com/help/coder/ug/call-cc-code-from-matlab-code.html

I found how to create variable in matlab based on header file with structure definition, but I don't know how to decast this variable to access values inside the structure.
Random and simplified version of the function is used below to make it more clear.
Code in MATLAB function in Simulink is following

```
function [d1,d2] = fcn()

out = coder.opaque('outStruct');
a = 1.5;
b = 2.5;
out = coder.ceval('myfunction',a,b);

% here I don't know how to extract d1 and d2 from "out"
```

In Simulink -> Model Settings -> Simulation Target header with structure definition and header and source file with function are specified

header with structure definition createStruct.h

```
#include <stdbool.h>
struct outStruct{
    float d1;
    float d2;
    bool isValid;
};
```

header with function definition func.h

```
#include "createStruct.h"

struct outStruct myfunction(float a, float b);
```

source file with function definition func.c

```
#include "func.h"

struct outStruct myfunction(float a, float b)
{
   struct outStruct str;
   str.d1 = a*b;
   str.d2 = a/b; 
   str.isValid = true;
   return str;
}
```

I tried out.d1 but i obviously didn't work. Somewhere is was recommended to use cast() function, but it is not clear how.

Comment: “Opaque” means you can’t see inside it. It is meant to encapsulate types that don’t have an equivalent in MATLAB, you can only receive them as outputs from a function and then pass them into another function. You want to use [`coder.cstructname`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/coder.cstructname.html).